# GeoJson and openlayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson

What is the correct way to fetch vector features from the server using GeoJson?

```
{
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "features" : [ {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : {
      "x" : 14.8802,
      "y" : 22.1043,
      "z" : "NaN",
      "m" : "NaN"
    },
    "properties" : {
      "date" : 1472936467273,
      "device" : null,
      "longitude" : 14.8802,
      "latitude" : 22.1043,
      "mi_PRINX" : 1,
      "id" : 1
    }
  }]
}
```

The map shows no points.

```
  var dynamicFeatures = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: new ol.source.Vector({
          format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
          url: "http://localhost:9090/map/layers"
        })
      });

      // Map
      this.mapObject = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        controls: [],
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          dynamicFeatures
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [949282, 6002552],
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
```

URL is correct.

Could it be because the z and m values? these are generated automatically from the server...

Regards,
Ido

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your geoJson should be as below:

```
{
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "features" : [
{ 
"type" : "Feature",
"geometry":  {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [14.8802, 22.1043]
    },
    "properties" : {
      "date" : 1472936467273,
      "device" : null,
      "longitude" : 14.8802,
      "latitude" : 22.1043,
      "mi_PRINX" : 1,
      "id" : 1
    }
  }
]
}
```

**Reference :** 
http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html